# Program that outputs a Visual Studio solution file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can I write a C# program that outputs a Visual Studio C# Console Application? For example, I'd like to put something such as `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` into the main function, which would result in a .sln file placed into the local file system.  Is this even possible?

I know this can be done with something like Excel. Using Interop, I can create an Excel workbook, write some data to it, and then save the file. How can I do something like this with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, you can.  What is your specific question?  Have you even tried?

Comment: I have looked into it, just not sure where to start. What tools do I need? For instance for Excel, you use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Is there something similar for Visual Studio?

Comment: There is no MS API for creating sln files.  There's little business case for it as it is an implementation detail of the IDE.

Comment: Are you aware of exactly what Visual Studio is and what it's intended for? It almost sounds like you think it's an end-user application like Excel.

Comment: I'm aware. I'm trying to give a pertinent example of similar functionality that I'm describing...and I've written created and saved .xlsx files in directly in code, and I would like to see if that's possible with .sln files. A programmer using Visual Studio is an end-user.

Comment: Do you know `csc` the C# compiler and `msbuild`?

Comment: OK, well like empi says in his answer, you can certainly write a C# program that creates a .sln and a .csproj and a .cs file and then launches Visual Studio to start up with this project as the current project. But it does sound like a rather strange thing to do.

Comment: I don't, but I will look into it.

Comment: Yes RenniePet that is what I want, regardless of how bizarre it sounds. Do you have any suggestions aside from those stated on how to get started?

Comment: My only suggestion is that you create a project by hand similar to what you want to create automatically, then examine what the .sln, .csproj and .cs files look like. Then write a C# program that creates those three files and writes them to disk. Then use the Process.Start() method to launch Visual Studio, giving it the filename of the .sln file as argument. Oh, and I don't think you need to worry about MSBuid.

Comment: And don't worry about your question being put "on hold" or being down-voted - happens to me too.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Solution files (.sln) and project files (.csproj) are simply <strike>xml</strike> text files so you should not have any problems with it. Since these are xml files you don't additional tools or APIs, especially for such not complicated project as you described.

Also when it comes to generating source files Visual Studio is closely integrated with T4 templates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx.